# Maven - dependency management in parent and import scope

Tags: java, maven

The setup is the following:

I am using Maven and I would like to use as a parent POM some artifact that has a number of dependencies in the dependencyManagement section. But I would also like to have a dependencyManagement section in my POM as well, because my artifact will be the parent pom of some other submodules.

Example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>sub-module-01</module>
        <module>sub-module-02</module>
    </modules>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Let's say that both these parent poms define a version for some dependency (let's say the version for jackson), but each has a different version.

When I define that dependency in one of my submodules, which version will be resolved?

I am not sure how to search for this situation on google.

Comment: what do you mean by ` both these parent poms` ? There is only one parent. Are you referring to `spring-boot-dependencies` as a parent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, Maven resolves using the closest version declaration.

My best guess would be that the one from the import in the dependency management section would be preferred, since it is closer to the location where the dependency is used:

- dependency -> imported dependency in parent pom = 2 hops
- dependency -> parent pom -> dependencyManagement in parent pom = 3 hops

But really, just try it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let us according to the different case:
Firstly, The simplest case is NO pom dependency import tag in any pom's dependencyManagement  section,  everything is clear and the dependency declaration will make a really affect with the closest dependency and properties such as exclude will inherit from parent pom and the exclusion with be merged .

Secondly, if the there is a direct declaration in any of each pom's DM section, this declaration will be used for this jar . if not, the closest import dependency declaration if exists will be used to the jar/pom's version. Here the closest mean is the distance to the pom and super pom or ,super super pom.  But Not The transitivity distance!

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be the version from import. Because the import 
DependencyManagement Just do a replace of dependencies. so Parent dependency will be overwritten by the import dependency. I do not verify this. Just a guess.

---

I Just do an experiment to check this situation.
Firstly. I define a dependency of netty-handler.
In my maven repository netty-handler version contain:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I create one test_parent pom project with this content in pom.xml

```
<groupId>dm-test</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-test-pom</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--  define a dependency in super parent pom with version  4.1.8.Final -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

and then create a pom project for import:

```
<groupId>dm-test</groupId>
<artifactId>import-pom</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!--  define a dependency in super parent pom with version  4.1.9.Final -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Finally, I create a war project with the parent_pom and import_pom, like this:

```
<groupId>dm-test</groupId>
<artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>dm-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-test-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dm-test</groupId>
            <artifactId>import-pom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

finally, We can see the dependency jar version is **4.1.8.Final**

So, My guess is wrong. sorry about that.
[image]

Comment: As Apache Document Says:
This scope is only supported on a dependency of type pom in the <dependencyManagement> section. It indicates the dependency to be replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified POM's <dependencyManagement> section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope